# Pass request to model form using generic view in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I using Django and a generic view "django.views.generic.create_update.create_object"
I have a model form wich i pass to the generic view:

```
url(r'^add$', create_object, {'template_name':'tpl.html','form_class':MyModelForm,'post_save_redirect':'/'},name = 'add'),
```

I need to get current user in my ModelForm.save method..
But i can't find way to get it, please help me to find convinient way?

`class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):`

```
class Meta:
    model = MyModel


def save(self,*a,**b):
    MyModel.save(user=request.user) #how can i get here request.user?
```

In common way the question is - how can i accsess request params in forms passed to generic view.

Comment: hmm, i'm curious about this as well. do you mind writing your own generic handler, or must you use the standard one and make it work here? the former i have done, but not yet the latter...

Comment: preferably i want to use generic views. I see one solution to use middleware for example to attach request.user direct to MyModelForm, but i have also problems there (MyModelForm instanse changed from import to import..i don't know why but i have different class objects instances in save method and my middleware function, and i loose my attached parametr in save).
Other way i think it can be done in apply_extra_context it can be used something like this context[key] = value(request), but it use only context[key] = value() ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thnx this helps) I have some problems this syntax and _meta attr and i finished with this

`def create_object_with_request(request, *args, **kwargs):`

```
def inject_request(fun):

    def helper(*args, **kwargs):
        finst = fun(*args, **kwargs)
        finst.request = request
        return finst

    helper._meta = fun._meta
    return helper
kwargs['form_class'] = inject_request(kwargs['form_class'])
return create_object(request,*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could probably hack something up to inject the request into the form instantiation, but why would you bother? Generic views are meant as a quick-and-easy solution to the basic requirements only. As soon as you start needing massive customisations, you might as well just write the actual view yourself. It's not very much code, after all.

Answer (score 1):

Look at that:

```
url(r'^add$', create_object_with_request, {'template_name':'tpl.html','form_class':MyModelForm,'post_save_redirect':'/'},name = 'add'),
```

,

```
def create_object_with_request(request, *args, **kwargs):
    def inject_request(fun):
        def helper(*args, **kwargs):
            return fun(*args, request=request, **kwargs)
        return helper
    kwargs['form_class'] = inject_request(kwargs['form_class'])
    return create_object(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

So you have passed request to your class constructor. Or you can add it as attribute:

```
def create_object_with_request(request, *args, **kwargs):
    def inject_request(fun):
        def helper(*args, **kwargs):
            res = fun(*args, **kwargs)
            res.request = request
            return res
        return helper
    kwargs['form_class'] = inject_request(kwargs['form_class'])
    return create_object(request, *args, **kwargs)
```